# Como exportar dados do Sublime 3

Tags: exportação, sublime-text-3

Gostaria de saber como exportar os dados do sublime 3, os pacotes que utilizo e configurações. Infelizmente ele não tem nenhuma forma automatizada e ágil de fazer isso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A melhor maneira é sincronizar a pasta do usuário, existem várias maneiras de fazer isso - dropbox, git e do jeito manual.

Os pacotes instalados estão registrados no Package Control.sublime-settings, que está localizado na pasta do usuário, não precisa sincronizar nada além disso. Um bom guia para sincronização pode ser encontrado [aqui](https://packagecontrol.io/docs/syncing).

Você também pode dar uma olhada [nesse pacote](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Sublimall).

Resposta encontrada em: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24254397/how-can-i-export-import-settings-of-sublime-text-3-from-one-pc-to-another-using